# Recover lost code from compiled apk

Tags: java, android, apk, recover

I have an issue here..and its making me really nervous.

I was working on this game, and it was going great, so I took a copy of it on my laptop to work do some work while away from my computer.

long story short, hard-drive failure + poor back ups led to me losing a very important class.

Is there a way to decompile the apk to retrieve the bit of code that was lost? It isn't overly complicated or sophisticated, its just that its impossible to re-write it without reading every. single. line. of. code. in the entire application since it initializes a LOT of classes and loads a bunch of stuff in a specific way.

With a quick google search I was able to find apktool, which decompiles it into a bunch of .smali files, which I don't think were designed for human reading.

All I need to recover is one very big method in the class. I found the smali file that contains it and I think I found the line where it starts. something like

> .method public declared-synchronized load(Lcom/X/X/game/X;)I

Anyone help would be appreciated since I would have to scrap the entire game without this method.

Comment: That's why you use source control (off-site, obviously).

Answer (score 5):

A quick google resulted in a way to decompile apks ([decompile apk to java source](http://a4apphack.com/security/sec-code/extract-android-apk-from-market-and-decompile-it-to-java-source)). However, even though it results in java code, you probably won't have any variable names (just default ones like `param1`) as those are unrecoverably removed when you compile the source code to byte code, also, depending on the decompiler, for/foreach loops will be while loops instead, if/else blocks might not represent your original control flow due to compiler optimization.

As a general advise: Use some sort of source control. On your own server, paid account with github doesn't matter what, but use source control. Even if you are just one person developing on a project. It helps with this situation, it helps with reverting to a previous version, it helps finding a bug you introduced. When the tools are available, use them.